How to securely interact with a smart contract using Web3.js?
I'm currently developing a decentralized application (dApp) on the Ethereum blockchain, and I'm using Web3.js to interact with my deployed smart contract. Here's the setup I have so far:
My smart contract is deployed on the Ethereum Sepolia testnet.
I'm using Metamask to connect the user's wallet.
Here's the basic code I'm using to call a getBalance function from the smart contract:
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);

const contractABI = [
    // ABI of the smart contract
];
const contractAddress = "...";

const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);

async function getBalance() {
    try {
        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        const balance = await contract.methods.getBalance().call({ from: accounts[0] });
        console.log("Balance:", balance);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
    }
}


While the function works, I have a few concerns about best practices and security:

Is there a way to minimize gas usage when calling a
smart contract method?
Are there any security vulnerabilities in the way I'm using Web3.js to interact with the contract?
Would it be    better to use Ethers.js
instead of Web3.js? If so, what are the key    advantages?

Any advice, suggestions, or code improvements would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!


Is there a way to minimize gas usage when calling a smart contract
method?

The code you pasted above doesn't use gas, it's a read-only function.
In case of write functions/transactions, gas usage depends on how the smart contract is written. What you can decide is the how much priority fees you wanna way. Usually we let the library to decide the fee, but you can manually set the values too. More details in docs. Higher the priority fees, faster the execution.

Are there any security vulnerabilities in the way I'm using Web3.js to
interact with the contract?

No, you are only reading the contract, no issues. But when sending transactions(directly from the scripts, without using browser wallets), you'll have to store the private key of your wallet, make sure you keep it inside the .env file, and don't accidently push it on github.

Would it be better to use Ethers.js instead of Web3.js? If so, what
are the key advantages?

Yes, I personally would suggest using ethers js because of simplicity and light weight. You can check many differences in discussions like these.
